# Array inside of an Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I have a 2D array that returns an array.

```
Object[][] sample = new Object[1][1];
//ok just imagine sample already has an array inside of it
```

How do I retrive the array within the 2d array?

I have tried to create a new array with the value,

```
object[] = sample[0][0];
```

but it just creates an error.

When I print the value of

```
sample[0][0]
```

it returns the value:
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@4e25154f

I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: Array with length 0. Why ?

Comment: try sample[0][0].getClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample[0][0]` is `Object` not `int[]`, `sample[0]` can be one dimensional array or any `Object`, note that arrays are also `Object` in java.

To print multidimensional array you can use `Arrays.deepToString(twoDarray)` but this does not work if you have stored *specifically* `Object`.

Moreover, `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@4e25154f` is the result of default `toString` representation of the `Object` stored at `sample[0][0]` which is I think an *array*. To print array you can use `Arrays.toString(int[])`.

I ***guess*** this is what you are trying to do,

```
Object[][] obj = new Object[1][1];
obj[0][0] = new int[]{0,1,0,2};
System.out.println(obj);
//To get int[]
int[] arr= (int[]) obj[0][0];//Need to cast to the int[] specifically
//because it's currently stored as an Object
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1db9742
[0, 1, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

sample[0][0] returns the object not int. First you need to downcast it and then retrieve integer value

For example :-

```
CustomObject co = (CustomObject)sample[0][0]; // downcast here
```

then retrieve the required field from your custom object